# MySql ODBC Windows XP to Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows, vb.net, odbc

I am trying to port a large application from Windows XP to Windows 7. This application MUST work on both platforms side by side as I have 22 client machines and they are all currently Windows XP but will one by one over time be converted to Windows 7.

I have a MySql database that works fine in XP and has been for a few years. On my first Windows 7 machine, it fails when I run the line of code to open a connection to the db:

MyOdbcConnection.Open()

The error is "ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".

To try to fix it, I downloaded the latest ODBC 5.2 drivers from MySql. I downloaded BOTH the 32bit and 64bit ones. I went into the ODBC Data Source Administrator for BOTH the 32bit and 64bit and added my datasource successfully for this db for a User DSN, System DSN, and File DSN. I can also successfully connect to the db from the MySql workbench.

This is my connection string. It's the same as the other working machine except that one is using the 5.1 driver.

```
Dim MySqlConString As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Driver};" & _ "SERVER=myserver;" & _ "DATABASE=mydb;" & _ "UID=root;" & _ "PASSWORD=mypw;" & _ "OPTION=3" – Jason Shoulders 3 hours ago
```

Despite being able to add the data source and connect to the db via workbench, I continue to get an error when I run my exe. Any suggestions?

Comment: Er... Workbench does not use ODBC, it uses the native protocol. What does your DSN string look like?

Comment: This is my connection string. It's the same as the other working machine except that one is using the 5.1 driver.

Dim MySqlConString As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Driver};" & _
                                 "SERVER=myserver;" & _
                                 "DATABASE=mydb;" & _
                                 "UID=root;" & _
                                 "PASSWORD=mypw;" & _
                                 "OPTION=3"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: vb.net I think making the driver 5.2w instead of 5.2 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed to have:

```
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver}
```

Seems lame. I'm not sure where the "w" came from.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#mysql-connector-odbc-5-1 under the '64 bit version of the driver' headline

Comment: @Jesse The "w" doesn't mean 64-bit.  It is the Unicode version of the driver.  With the 5.2 line of the MySQL ODBC driver they have both Ansi and Unicode versions (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-odbc-versions.html)).  Thus the driver names are correspondingly `MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver` and `MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver`.  Both Ansi and Unicode are available in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

There is little point in adding a user, system and file DSN as your code is not using any of them. You are using what is usually referred to as a "DSN-less" connection. If you were using any of your created DSNs your connection string would be "DSN=my_created_dsn" or FILEDSN=path_to_file. As you are using "DRIVER={xxx}" all you are doing is telling the ODBC driver manager which driver to load and the other attributes in the connection string tell the driver what mysql db to connect to. The name you use for xxx needs to be exactly the name of the driver as shown in the odbc drivers tab. If you are going to continue connecting like this you can delete all your DSNs.

Answer (score 0):

Your 32bit program will not find a 64bit odbc driver. Try setting up the 32bit driver with the following in a command window

```
%WINDIR%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Fox Pro 9.0 under Windows XP Pro SP3 with 32 bit

I had the same problem but id did NOT work with:

Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver} or with Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver}

IT WORKED!!! with:

Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver} or with Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver}

Try it.